# Editing Title, Sub title and Text

Tags: user-expectation, ux-field, google-materials-design

In the web app we are making theres a Material Design Card where theres a User type that has the permission to edit content he posted, so heres the question.

When he clicks to edit this content every line is going to convert to a Text field or Text Area as needed BUT the TITLE for example has a bigger size font so we don't know if the new words on the input of the title should use the same font size as the Title or it should be the same font size as a body?

(THE "NOMBRE CORTO" SHOULD TRANSFORM TO A TEXT FIELD WHEN EDITING MODE ITS ON AND SO THE SUB HEADING AND BODY)

Below you guys can find the screen shot and as always the material design link related to this subject.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html

[image]

Comment: What would be the potential benefit of having it be the same size as the body? It seems to me if you're going to display it in large font then you should edit it in large font.

Comment: Well, since im using Material Design Guidelines if the input text is too big it has the possibility to touch the label text BUT in this material design guide theres a Taller text field variation that may work if you believe that it should be the same size @DasBeasto

Answer (score 1):

i'd suggest to retain the **same** font-size when editing each field, for if you go with a smaller font-size ,  it may seem odd when the font-size resets when the user has completed editing. (unless you do some awesome looking transistions though)

We used a similar approach when editing the *title*  for our app , which was Delivery Recipient name form field.

But it should be noted , that when editing any sub-text , i.e text smaller than your body size , eg: disclaimers, alternate delivery address etc ,care should be taken that they should scale to the body's font-size when editing.

Just my two cents :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to keep **consistency**. The user recognizes the title by its big font size. If the user edits the title, he doesn't expect it to change to something that looks like body text.

Did you check if it touches the label text indeed?